# React native: flatlists inside scrollview android performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Since I heard this from RN docs 'Never put a flat list inside scroll view wrapper'.

But I have one huge page to make and it requires a scroll itself, and there are children flat lists as well.

Of course, this causes a horrible scroll lag user experience, so there is anyone experienced the same kind of problem as me? What was a solution to this?

This is my snippet.

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

        <ScrollView
          ref={c => this.detailScrollView = c}
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#f8faf9" }}
        >
          <FlatList1 goodsDetails />
          <FlatList2 goodsPriceSelector />
          <FlatList3 bestreviews />
          <FlatList4 sellerGoods />
          <FlatList5 sameCategoryGoods />

        </ScrollView>

      </View>
```

edit:

Today, thanks to @MaieonBrix I replaced my childeren flatlists to SectionLists, could feel a bit of improvement. In test android build it still janky, but I think I'm on the right track. I will keep this updated.

```
{descImgs && !!descImgs.length  ?
              <SectionList
                sections={descImgs.slice(0,2)}
                ref={c => this.goodsDesc = c}
                style={{ marginTop: 22, marginBottom: 22 }}
                keyExtractor={item => item}
                renderItem={function ({ img }) {
                  return (
                    <View style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
                      {img.includes("https://") ? (
                          <FastImage
                            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
                            style={{ height: width, width: width, }}
                            source={{ uri: img }}
                          />
                        ) : <TextNoScailing>상세이미지가 없습니다.</TextNoScailing>}
                    </View>
                  );
                }.bind(this)}
              />
```

Comment: Why do you need so many flatlist ? Can you use the SectionList component instead ? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html since it's, by the docs, "A performant interface for rendering sectioned lists, supporting the most handy features:"

Comment: I think this design has a problem. it is meaningless. if only every FlatList has some items chang it to view. if everyone can scroll more, I suggest change the UI design

Comment: @MaieonBrix SectionsList I didn't know about. I should change components.

Comment: @Lenoarod I too think the design is a bit heavy, but this was confirmed by CEO. By now, I should stick with this design...

Comment: @SalJeong You should give it a try though, get the data, transform it to please the SectionList component (`data={[ {title: "section title, can be null", data: ["array of whatever data type you'd like, each list item will receive it's data"]}]`) and see if there is an improvement. You could even memoize the data transformation to avoid useless re-renders.

Comment: but in this case if there is a real constraint of not using sectionList you can try tiny bits of improvement by avoiding useless re-renders. However, if there is not technical constraints I suggest to do a proof of concept, show this to the ceo and ask a raise \o/

Answer (score 0):

Well thats true.Flatlist would not work fine under scrollview in android because both using same gestures in same direction.Possible solutions
1) You can define your custom gestures using pan responder library "which is a bit tough for a biggner"

2) Disable/Enable scroll using conditions.e-g: When you're touching a flatlist then disable scroll of scrollView Similarly when on scrollView then disable for Flatlist.

The above solution is for android only because for iOS it will work fine automatically.Similarly you've to provide horizontal margin for flatlist container .Becuse only then use can touch the scroll view container near the boundries.
Hope it clears

Comment: Yes I found the problem is android-only... I can try your solutions

Comment: How did it go? What did you end up doing? @SalJeong

Comment: @AndrésLiu
I did with nested flatlist.... the wrapper flatlist have only [1] as data and there are tons of child flatlists and it worked nicely so far.

Comment: Can you please post your demo solution here?